# getDocs not returning data from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

This is from a react project with react-router and Firebase. I'm using react-router's loader function for fetching some data from Firebase firestore. Instead of returning data, the loader function is throwing "Could not fetch projects" as is mentioned in the code below despite the config and read/write security rules being suitable. This obviously means that there's come problem with the response but I don’t know how to fix the issue.

```
function Homepage() {
  return (
    <>
      <HeroSection />
      <FeaturedProjects />
    </>
  );
}

export default Homepage;

export async function loader() {
  const response = await getDocs(collection(db, "projects"));
  if (!response.ok) {
    return json({ message: "Could not fetch projects" }, { status: 500 });
  } else {
    return response;
  }
}
```

I've omitted irrelevant code but I'd be happy to share any other information/code needed to better assess the situation.

**Update:** getting rid of the `if(!response.ok){...)` block is solving the problem and the desired response is getting logged into the console.

Comment: From the description you've given, we only know that `response.ok` is not `true`. Could you `console.log` the response to get more information about what exactly is wrong? Or check the network requests in your browser to see if there is a more helpful error message

Comment: What are you expecting `response` to be?  It definitely doesn't have a property called `ok`.  I suggest reviewing the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) to understand what it returns.

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom, I tried logging the response to the console but nothing shows up. Checking the network requests seems like a good lead and I will get back to you with the findings. 
@DougStevenson, you're right `.ok` is not a property on the intended data. It is a property on the response interface whose value is a boolean stating whether a response was successfully returned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom, @DougStevenson update: I got rid of the entire portion below `const response = await...` and logged response into the console and it worked! My bad, seems like the react router loader method I used for dealing with errors was creating the problem. I will change the error-handling code. In any case, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDocs` from Firestore returns a `QuerySnapshot` object, not an HTTP-like response object, so `response.ok` condition is not relevant here.
 You just need a `try-catch` handling and it should work as expected:

```js
try {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "projects"));
  const projects = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  return { projects }; 
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error fetching projects:", error);
  throw new Error("Could not fetch projects"); 
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Like I mentioned in the update, I realised the problem had something to do with the way I was treating the value returned but couldn’t figure out the exact reason. Thanks for the explanation!